# Scale and skew images using jQuery or AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax

Im trying to find a way either with ajax or jquery that can angle the picture in the point I wanted. For example I want to have four point in my background (picture #1) and then have a picture which every corner of that pointed and adjusted to my desire points (picture #2).

Its going to be dynamic and basically picture #1 will be static but picture #2 will be changing with the next/previews key. Kind of like gallery.
These points and image may vary in different galleries and has to have ability to get modified.

[image: Valid XHTML].

Any suggestions?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: How far have you gotten with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most JS libraries should provide the functions you need to rotate/skew images in the way you describe.

For example, Jquery has a plugin called "Scale" that can do it:

http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/scale

Likewise scripty2 (scriptaculous 2) offers it as well in the scripty2fx framework:

http://scripty2.com/doc/scripty2_fx_section.html

CSS3 also provides techniques to rotate/skew/scale images using transforms. The advantage of using a JS framework is cross-browser compatability. If you think you'll be exclusively targeting a browser that supports CSS3, you can use these/those:

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-2d-transforms/

Let me know if you need more specific instructions than that, or if you need help with something more specific/narrow.